# Text Input has 1 pixel difference on my iPhone

Tags: html, css, less

I have this irritating problem with one of my sign in and signup forms. The forms input on my mobile are 1px longer and i'm not exactly sure why

[image: Desktop] Desktop VS Mobile [image: Mobile]

I know one is sign in and sign up but that's irrelevant so don't worry about the difference its the same on both forms

Here is my code for my LESS

```
@inputradius: 4px;

input{
  &[type=text], &[type=email], &[type=password]{

    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 4.5px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: @inputradius;
    &.noleft{
      border-top-left-radius: 0;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    }
  }
}

.inputimg{
  border-top-left-radius: @inputradius;
  border-bottom-left-radius: @inputradius;
  padding: 4px;
  top: 10px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: none;
}
```

And my html for that bit

```
<div class="control">
   <img class='inputimg' src="images/inputs/username.png"><input placeholder="Username" class="noleft" type="text" name="username" value="{{ Request::old('username') }}"/>
</div>
<div class="control">
   <img class="inputimg" src="images/inputs/email.png"><input placeholder="Email" class="noleft" type="email" name="email" value="{{ Request::old('email') }}"/>
</div>
<div class="control">
   <img class="inputimg" src="images/inputs/password.png"><input placeholder="Password" class="noleft" type="password" name="password"/ value="{{ Request::old('password') }}">
</div>
```

Even code pen appears differently
http://codepen.io/albermashy/pen/LNaEEG

Comment: If anybody needs the LESS translated to CSS just comment here and i'll add it

Comment: try to add it, so or add a https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: did try `box-sizing: border-box;` ??

Comment: You havent defined any height to either of your elements. Thus its the font size inside the input field that will determine the height of the input, and the height of the image will determine the height of the image. If the mobile device has another default font size the height will differ.

Comment: I hate myself to ask this but did u check ur browser zooming? it is more than 100%? u changed anytime by mistake

Comment: @RudiDudi I've added a codepen since jsfiddle didn't support LESS

Comment: @OleHaugset Do you have any height suggestions?

Comment: Try to fix the height of the form elements!

Comment: Use box-sizing:border-box; for your input field. When you add a border to it, the border is normally added outside of the box's content, thus leaving it with an actual height of 22 pixels, instead of 20. When uses border-box the border is added within the height parameters of the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the input field, and it should be fine:

```
height:30px;
box-sizing:border-box;
```

When you add a border to objects, the border is normally added outside of the box's content, thus leaving it with an actual height of 22 pixels, instead of 20. When using `border-box` the border is added within the height parameters of the container.

Your image is an actual height of 30 as well due to this mathematical equation:

Height 20px + 4px padding bottom + 4px padding top + 1px border top + 1px border bottom.

**EDIT:**

If floating your elements is no problem with the rest of your setup, you can add box-sizing:border-box to both the image and the input, and left float them. This will take care of the offset problem between the two, and you won't have to use the `top:10px;`

Total css:

```
@inputradius: 4px;

input{
  &[type=text], &[type=email], &[type=password]{
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 4.5px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: @inputradius;
    height: 30px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    float:left;
    &.noleft{
      border-top-left-radius: 0;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    }
  }
}
.control {
  clear:both;
  padding:20px 0;
}
.inputimg{
  border-top-left-radius: @inputradius;
  border-bottom-left-radius: @inputradius;

  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: none;
  height: 30px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  float:left;
}
```

Comment: It works on desktop but the input field is 1 pixel lower now on mobile

Comment: It may have something to do with the `top` attribute

Comment: Is the image and the input field the same height, but offset from each other with 1 px, or is the input field 1px taller?

Comment: They are the same height but the input has an offset of 1px going down

Comment: I updated my answer, since Im to lazy to register for codepen and post a solution there

Comment: Still no luck. On mobile it is now only 1px taller (at the bottom)

Comment: Superb, glad to help

Comment: I consider this a hack, not a solution. While the CSS is perfectly acceptable, changing the box model to make it work is like moving the goal posts to score a goal. The more appropriate answer would have been to find a fix for the model he's using.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i miss read the question, my mistake

This appears to be an iPhone rendering issue to fix this just give it an exact `height`, you have gave the form a class of `.noleft` but you haven't done anything in CSS

Add `height:27px` to that class this should fix the issue

Try this:

```css
.inputimg{
  border-top-left-radius: @inputradius;
  border-bottom-left-radius: @inputradius;
  padding: 3px;
  top: 3px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: none;
}

.noleft {
  height: 27px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

Comment: There is no "I Think here". You have any "I think" .. do it in the comment. This place is for "Answers"

Comment: I tried different heights they all ended up with 1px difference for the iphone
I think it may be something to do with the paddings margins and top

Comment: yea thats what i put as my first response. i changed the .inputting and added a .noleft try this and see if this works i will have to add to the riginal answer i gave